# Configuring BIND to use VM's DNS for specific domain

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I work on a project for which I use an Ubuntu server vm on an Ubuntu host.

The VM runs all the services / webapps through haproxy and nginx and serves it on the domain (xyz.com).

I manually modify my resolv.conf to use the VMs IP address as the nameserver and I can run my app on the host browser.

The problem is I am modifying an auto-generated file (resolv.conf) and I need to do it each time.

Is there a smart way to say:

-- are you accessing xyz.com?

-- if yes use VM's DNS server, else use the hosts

Comment: Are you asking about BIND (in which case the file is `named.conf`), or just the system's resolver libraries (which use `resolv.conf`)?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I am modifying an auto-generated file (resolv.conf) and
>   I need to do it each time.

You can fix this issue,
just make "chmod +i /etc/resolv.conf" if you use extended attributes of fs and fs like ext3 or ext4(maybe it works on another, but I'm note sure)

Issue with dns you can fix using different views(for bind dns server): http://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views